# What should I do if I want the value of the dgv1(datagridview) to be shown on a different form?

Tags: c#

**Form1**

```c#
namespace erpmam
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MySqlDB mySqlDB;
        SqlDataAdapter adpt;
        DataTable dt;
        SqlConnection con;
        public void showdata()
        {
            adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("select deptmt_id, deptmt_name, deptmt_seq, reg_ymdtms, mod_ymdtms from sys_department;",con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adpt.Fill(dt);
            dgv1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mySqlDB = new MySqlDB("server=······");
        }

        private SqlDataAdapter MySqlDataAdapter(string v, MySqlConnection con)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void BTN_INSERT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sql = "";
            sql += " select";
            sql += " deptmt_id, deptmt_name, deptmt_seq, reg_ymdtms, mod_ymdtms";
            sql += " from sys_department";
            sql += " where deptmt_id like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%'";

            DataTable dt = mySqlDB.ExecuteReader(sql, mySqlDB.DBConnection());

            dgv1.SuspendLayout();
            dgv1.Rows.Clear();
            for (int idx = 0; idx < dt.Rows.Count; idx++)
            {
                DataRow r = dt.Rows[idx];
                dgv1.Rows.Add(1);
                dgv1[0, idx].Value = r["deptmt_id"].ToString().Trim();
                dgv1[1, idx].Value = r["deptmt_name"].ToString().Trim();
                dgv1[2, idx].Value = r["deptmt_seq"].ToString().Trim();
                dgv1[3, idx].Value = r["reg_ymdtms"].ToString().Trim();
                dgv1[4, idx].Value = r["mod_ymdtms"].ToString().Trim();
            }
            dgv1.ResumeLayout();
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sql = "";
            sql += " select";
            sql += "    deptmt_id, deptmt_name, deptmt_seq, reg_ymdtms, mod_ymdtms";
            sql += " from sys_department";
            sql += "   where deptmt_name like '%" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "%'";

            DataTable dt = mySqlDB.ExecuteReader(sql, mySqlDB.DBConnection());

            dgv1.SuspendLayout();
            dgv1.Rows.Clear();
            for (int idx = 0; idx < dt.Rows.Count; idx++)
            {
                DataRow r = dt.Rows[idx];
                dgv1.Rows.Add(1);
                dgv1[0, idx].Value = r["deptmt_id"].ToString().Trim();
                dgv1[1, idx].Value = r["deptmt_name"].ToString().Trim();
                dgv1[2, idx].Value = r["deptmt_seq"].ToString().Trim();
                dgv1[3, idx].Value = r["reg_ymdtms"].ToString().Trim();
                dgv1[4, idx].Value = r["mod_ymdtms"].ToString().Trim();
            }
            dgv1.ResumeLayout();
        }

        private void dgv1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 Form3 = new Form3();
            Form3.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```c#
namespace erpmam
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource =······");
        MySqlCommand command;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void executeMyQuery(string query)
        {
            try
            {
                openConnection();
                command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Query Executed");
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Query Not Executed");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                closeConnection();
            }
        }
        public void openConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }

        public void closeConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO sys_department(DEPTMT_ID, DEPTMT_NAME, DEPTMT_SEQ, REG_YMDTMS) VALUES(" + textBox1.Text + ',' + textBox2.Text + ','+ textBox3.Text + ','+ "NOW()" +")";
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
            try
            {
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("adding normally");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            connection.Close();
            this.Close();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form3**

```c#
namespace erpmam
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource = localhost; port = 3306; Initial Catalog = 'erp'; username = root; password=610822");
        MySqlCommand command;
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void executeMyQuery(string query)
        {
            try
            {
                openConnection();
                command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Query Executed");
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Query Not Executed");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                closeConnection();
            }
        }        public void openConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
        public void closeConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string updateQuery = " UPDATE sys_department"; 
            updateQuery +=       " SET DEPTMT_NAME = '" + textBox2.Text + "', DEPTMT_SEQ = '" + textBox3.Text + "', mod_ymdtms = NOW()";
            updateQuery +=       " where DEPTMT_ID = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(updateQuery, connection);
            try
            {
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("changed normally");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            connection.Close();
            this.Close();
        }
        private void btn_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string deleteQuery = " DELETE from sys_department"; 
            deleteQuery +=       " where DEPTMT_ID = '" + textBox1.Text + "' or DEPTMT_NAME = '" + textBox2.Text + "' or DEPTMT_SEQ = '" + textBox3.Text + "'" ;
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(deleteQuery, connection);
            try
            {
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("adding normally");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            connection.Close();
            this.Close();
        }
        private void btn_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply you can create a Global variable of `Datatabl`e to use it as source of Data and you can use it anywhere in your `Forms`

This is the GLobal Class

```
//make sure to import this System.Data
using System.Data;

class Global
 {
    private static DataTable source;
    public static DataTable Source
    {
        get
        {
            // Reads are usually simple
            return source;
        }
        set
        {
            // You can add logic here for race conditions,
            // or other measurements
            source = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In your first form

```
string connectString = "datasource=xxxx;port=3306;username=xxxx;password=;database=xxxxx;";
    MySqlConnection conn;
    MySqlCommand comm;
    MySqlDataReader read;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    Global mySource;

void getData() {
        string query = "Select * from tableName";
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
        conn.Open();
        comm = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        
        //setting up
        Global.Source = ds.Tables[0];

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        conn.Close();

    }
```

In you second Form

```
 public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Global.Source;
    }
```

Comment: There are no "global" variables in C#. Static variables aren't the same as global. Nonetheless, static variables are a bad idea for this kind of thing. It's like a bank decides to use a public park bench to put the money for the security company to come pick up later. Bad guys might help themselves too.

Comment: Well maybe this is a bad Idea of an answer to a question but `escaping` to a problem might work.

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can create static method in the class of form3 and accept one argument from DataGridView type and call this method from form1 and pass dg1 after filling it with rows then you can access it now from this static method...

```
private void dgv1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
      Form3 Form3 = new Form3();
      Form3.staticMethodToPassDGVBetweenTwoForms(dgv1);
      Form3.ShowDialog();
}

namespace erpmam {

     public partial class Form3 : Form {
     public Form3() {
        initializeComponent();
     }

     public static void staticMethodToPassDGVBetweenTwoForms(DataGridView dgv1){
       //do anything with dg1 now
     }
}
```